# How to save a file from a command prompt with python3+

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently learning Tkinter and I'm trying to save the file named 'hello.py' using the command prompt.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()
ttk.Button(root, text="Hello World").grid()
root.mainloop()
% python hello.py
```

Here is the error line:

```
>>> % python hello.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    % python hello.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think you are using the python console or REPL.  It's not a text editor.  Or, am I missing something?

Comment: No you’re right! I was wondering if you can save a .py from a python shell command.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to %save from python console which you opened by %python and not from the ipython/Jupiter shell.
Exit and return to ipython by Ctr-z

Comment: Sorry. I edit my question. % python hello.py and the error is; 

>>> % python hello.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    % python hello.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Starting python line with % is indeed a syntax error. I guess you meant to call the magic ipython command %%python (which is ipython alias and not python syntax)

Comment: But you are already inside python interpreter (>>>) and should call python command from the shell (%).

Comment: I appreciate your patience! I'm not sure to understand how I should call python command from the shell and how this will 'save' the file from the command line ?

Comment: Let’s start by opening a console and type “python hello.py”. In case you still don’t have the hello.py file just edit it with simple text editor.

Comment: hello.py is not a current .py file in the directory. I type line of code and I want to save that hello.py in where the python command shell is opened. So, python hello.py will generate an error since no such file exist in the directory. So, should I understand it is not possible to save from a command shell ? I have to edit in an editor and save my .py file with it ?

Comment: Basically yes. But if you are working with ipython console it has a special %save command. I guess you are not working with ipython